# good image optimizer that can be used?

Tags: optimization, image

Hai guys,

I want compress my images without changing the quality... Because my web application uses lots of images and when i inspected with **firebug** i found images size where huge...

- Are there any good image optimizer?

  I know there is [SmushIt](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/) from yahoo... Any other useful image optimizers?

Comment: Isn't this a better fit for superuser.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PNG images there are [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and [PNGCRUSH](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use imagemagick if you are using linux, google will offer you lots of examples to batch-process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio a great extension to install is the Image Optimizer. It uses the SmushIt service from Yahoo. It's great for processing a large number of files at once at the click of a button.

For more info and a download - http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/05/14/visual-studio-2010-image-optimizer-extension.aspx