# Very large PNG images animate optimisation

Tags: jquery

I have 3 large (7000px wide) transparent PNG images that are animating left to right. Performance is not too bad, but not great.

I need help with optimising this images so make jquery animation smooth.

I tried splitting them all up into slices (so its 10 separate PNG per background) which has helped, but still are quiet choppy.

Comment: *Performance is not too bad, but not great*...... WOW you have a computer! :)

Comment: if its an image, have you considered using jpg? alternatively you could also try a canvas on HTML5 supported browsers

Comment: @atif089 their png's are transparent..

Comment: Have you tried using OptiPNG (http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or PNGOUT (http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm)? Might not make the biggest difference, but always worth a shot.

Comment: yep @transparent so have to be png's. Just tried one of the images as a repeating background-image, and its actually worse performance, much slower.

Comment: @TomD Indeed and what if you try to load images in `<canvas>`, and animate it using canvas graphics methods? It might output the result smoother.

Comment: Point of interest, there _are_ ways to make JPGs emulate png transparency: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/10/29/clipping-jpeg-images-into-non-rectangular-polygons-using-polyclip-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, instead of using jquery's `animate`, using [CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) which should result in smoother animations.

From [Addy Osmani's Blog Post: CSS3 Transition Animations With jQuery Fallbacks](http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/):

> The benefit of transitions is that unlike JavaScript based animations,
>   they're hardware accelerated in certain browsers and mobile devices,
>   resulting in a potentially smoother overall animation than you would
>   normally experience.

Comment: Thanks @Zach L. The animations are based on loads of variables and movements depending on the users mouse, so not sure I could use CSS3 transitions.

Comment: Yea, not sure how complicated its gonna get, but perhaps you can offload some of it to css?  You can, of course, still use JS to change classes, etc... triggering transitions.  Perhaps you can update your question with a more detailed description of your functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm unsure if you can create dynamic drag style animations using CSS3? Using JqueryUI slider, I listen to the slider value and move a div based on this value. could this be done by CSS3?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure... I'll look into it later if I get a chance.  That _is_ however definitely info that should have been in the original question

Comment: thankyou, to be honest I didn't think it's possible through css3 so didn't ask

Comment: this looks interesting and could work: css3 animations using jquery http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have it just as one image, that way your browser only performs one http request to get the image and also the image could be compressed better and be it lighter than if you separate it in 7 pieces and compress each one, because there will be redundant data accross them.

For programs to optimize png's, instead of pasting links here I will give you two questions with some of these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060763/image-optimizer-for-images-used-on-the-web-jpg-gif-and-png
- [good image optimizer that can be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109351/good-image-optimizer-that-can-be-used)

Also see this [interesting article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) about optimizing images and the best approches.

Comment: I can't seem to find a reference, but pretty sure I've read, that in some edge cases (with exceptionally large files?) breaking into several HTTP requests can actually improve performance.

Comment: After searching for a bit longer, I think that you are probably correct in this case at least.

Comment: Sounds interesting, however I've now found out that iOS cannot display images as PNG images 7000px wide, it just displays ?. So I shall have to split them up.

Comment: What do you mean, "it just displays" ?

Comment: That link doesn't really answer my question.  ("it does not shown properly"), ("It is little question icon instead of image"),  ("iPad cannot display images with a w*h larger than...").   Are you getting a "little question icon?"

Comment: icon instead of image (missing image)